# Listar projetos criados dentro de grupo do gitlab por data de criação

Tags: libcurl, gitlab

estou iniciando com o Gitlab e tenho a seguinte demanda, precisamos pelo API identificar os projetos criados no ano de 2020 dentro de um determinado grupo de projetos do gitlab. Listando as seguintes informações: nome do projeto, data de criação, usuário.

Fiz alguma pesquisa e descobri que é possível pelo CURL usando [GET /projects](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#list-all-projects) no campo created_at

mas não entendi como posso listar todos os projetos e a sintaxe do comando pelo terminal.

desde já agradeço a ajuda de todos.